# How to store, access and retrieve Image files from Nodejs-Express ( MongoDB ) to Angular8 FrontEnd,

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular8

This is an Employee Management System, Profile images of Employees are uploaded and stored in API server (defined path).

I implemented the following steps.

[image]

**Step 1: API server Request - the sample API code**

```
router.get('/public/users-images/*', function(req, res) {
var filepath = __dirname +'/..'+req.url
fs.exists(filepath, (exists) => {
  if (exists) {
    var filepath = filepath
 } else {
   var filepath = __dirname +'/../public/users-images/user-image.png'
 }
})
var fileext = filepath.split('.') 
fs.readFile(filepath, function(err, buffer){
// console.log(base64Image);
   var base64Image = new Buffer(buffer, 'binary').toString('base64');
   res.send({img:'data:image/'+fileext[fileext.length -1]+';base64,' + base64Image});
 });
})
```

**Step 2: Front end request from Angular8 using the pipe method,**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Pipe({
  name: 'userImages'
})
export class UserImagesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(
     private http: HttpClient,
     private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) { }

  transform(img_name: string): any {

   this.http.get('/public/users-images/'+img_name).subscribe(result => {
     // You could also cache your result
     return result.img;

   });
  }
}
```

Now, My question is , How to access the images from API Server location and display it in the UI screen. I assume to use the below method.

Html template `<img [src]="'user-image.png' | userImages" class="responsive-12">`

I use **PIPE method** - Because the User List (User Information including the Profile images ) will be used in Search filter, Task Creation form etc., So I tried to implement it in common, And maybe In the future, there is a chance to implement it through CDN.

Am I doing it in the right way? Or will there be any vents for issues ?

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating it. Let the browser do the fetching of the image.

Simply output the correct path to the image in the view

```
<img [src]="'/public/users-images/' + username + '.png'" alt="" />
```

or if you want you could create a pipe for it, but only to output the correct path

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Pipe({
  name: 'userImages'
})
export class UserImagesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(
     private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) { }

  transform(img_name: string): any {
    return `/public/users-images/${img_name}.png`
  }
}
```

```
<img [src]="username | userImages" alt="" />
```

Comment: Hi @Leon Radley - `<img [src]="'/public/users-images/' + username + '.png'" alt="" />` it refers to UI server 'http://localhost:4200/public/users-images/Karthik_1587452462564.jpeg', But the images are retrives from API call 'http://localhost:3536/apiv1/public/users-images/Karthik_1587452462564.jpeg'

Comment: How are you going to serve the api when going live?

If you are going to use nginx or alike to map your api to  /api/
I would proxy the api into angulars dev server during development.
That way you can use the same url /apiv1/public/users-images/***

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md